# How do I use a vaporizer/humidifier?

Tags: air-conditioning, dryer, humidity

An attic has been converted into a bedroom and it's very uncomfortable to sleep in, the air is very dry. I bought a humidifier but it didn't come with instructions. This may be a silly question but I want to make sure: how do I use the humidifier? I filled it with water and plugged it in. Nothing has happened after 30 minutes. A sticker on it says that if it doesn't work the first time to add salt to the water and to refer to the (non-existing) instructions. On the box it says warm mist vaporizer, are vaporizers the same thing as a humidifiers?

EDIT: I added salt and now it's going a little bit, hardly any steam is coming out of it, should there be more?

Comment: Was the attic converted by a contractor, or was it a DIY project?

Comment: Small appliances are considered off topic.  Sounds like something you should call the manufacture about

Comment: @Tester101 yes it was a DIY and I suspect part of the problem is the insulation is not fully sealed off. Also the electric heaters really dry out the air.

Comment: @Celeritas You may be having problems with the space because it's improperly built.  Attic additions are never as easy as they seem. In a lot of places you're not allowed to simply convert attic space to living space, you have to restructure and it's not as simple as building a livable box in the attic.  Check local codes, and talk to local builders/contractors, they may be able to tell you why the space is so uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put salt in the water. After 10 minutes it started making a little steam and after 30 minutes it was making enough steam to actually notice a difference.